# Plugin to add functionality to sendEmailConfirmation (after) does not work

Tags: magento2, plugin

We are trying to add a functionality to send an additional email to the admin when a user has registered an account.

The core code we want to modify is located at `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php class: sendEmailConfirmation`.

The code we currently believe should work:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
    <plugin name="EmailAanpassing" type="Sprite\EmailAanpassing\Customer\Model\After" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
</type>    
</config>
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Sprite_EmailAanpassing" setup_version="1.0.0">
  <sequence>
   <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
  </sequence>
 </module>
</config>
```

**Sprite/EmailAanpassing/Customer/Model/After.php**

```
<?php
namespace Sprite\EmailAanpassing\Customer\Model;

use \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;


class After extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{

protected function afterSendEmailConfirmation()//Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer, $redirectUrl)//)//SomeType $iets)
{
       // sendmail test
       mail("email@domain.com","New Registration",'Hello World!');
}
}
?>
```

When adding to code directly to the core it works fine. The module's basic files are created via Mage2gen.

Magento ver. 2.1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins work only for public methods. Since `sendEmailConfirmation()` is a protected method, you can't able write plugin for that. Other way, you can write plugin for `createAccountWithPasswordHash()` which is the parent function of `sendEmailConfirmation()`.

Comment: Ah, of course, it is working now, thanks. This, in combination of overloading $subject, $result and returning $result to make it work with the "createAccountWithPasswordHash()" method.